# How to get certain attributes of an array of objects in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

I have an array of JSON object.

```
arr =  [{'a'=> 1, 'b'=> 2, 'c'=> 3}, {'a'=> 4, 'b'=> 5,'c'=> 6}, {'a'=> 4, 'b'=> 5,'c'=> 6}]
```

But I want an new array which select 'a' and 'c' attributes only:

```
new_arr = [{'a'=> 1, 'c'=> 3}, {'a'=> 4,'c'=> 6}, {'a'=> 4,'c'=> 6}]
```

I try to use map but for 1 attribute only `arr.map{|i| i['a']}`. 
What I am missing or any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of [**`slice`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) and pass the attributes you want to select

```
arr =  [{'a'=> 1, 'b'=> 2, 'c'=> 3}, {'a'=> 4, 'b'=> 5,'c'=> 6}, {'a'=> 4, 'b'=> 5,'c'=> 6}]

arr.map{|a| a.slice('a', 'c')}
#=> [{"a"=>1, "c"=>3}, {"a"=>4, "c"=>6}, {"a"=>4, "c"=>6}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`except`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except)

```
new_arr = arr.map{ |e| e.except('b') }
```

Comment: The only drawback is if there is `{'d' => 5}` you will get that as well

Comment: in that case, it should be `e.except('b','d')`

Answer (score 3):

Since, there are already answers describing usage of `slice` and `except`, I would provide another way here:

```
arr.map{|h| {'a' => h['a'], 'c' => h['c'] } }
#=> [{"a"=>1, "c"=>3}, {"a"=>4, "c"=>6}, {"a"=>4, "c"=>6}]
```

Note that `h` here is a particular object of the array being iterated inside `map`, which is a `Hash`.

Bit more of a code to be typed though. You could use `select` as well.

Comment: `ar` should be `h`, these are hashes, not arrays.

Comment: @Stefan : Edited for more clarity